# Find-Bar for website similar to Google Chromes

Tags: javascript, browser, find

can you please recommend a code that can be like this one? i tried implementing google search bar on my site but when i search, it just opens up google  and the pages that google  has cached on my site, the functionality that i want is like this Find Bar of google chrome that will only Search the entire page, for example when I typed `"A"` the results are there are `285 "A"` on the page. you might say that i should just use the built in Find Bar from the browser, the problem is the functionality of the find bar from firefox and other browsers are not similar to google chromes, that is why I'm looking for a code that can be similar to this one and can be used on other browsers.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which might work for you. This uses Regular Expressions to search for the string. You might need to modify the RegEx and the DOM nodes it searches for to make it more efficient. Doesn't include any logic to highlight the results. Just counts the occurrences and displays the count.

*Working demo here:* http://jsfiddle.net/ZCUvE/

**HTML**

```
​<div class="search">
    <input type="text" id="search" value="" placeholder="Search" />
    <span id="results"></span>
</div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

**CSS**

```
.search {
    width: 40%;
    background: #999;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 8px;
}
#results {
    background: #DDD;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 1px 3px;
    display: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
​$("#search").on("keyup", function()​ {
    if(this.value) {
        var results = 0;
        $("body").children().each(function() {
            var re = new RegExp($("#search").val(), "gi");
            var matches = $(this).text().match(re);
            results += matches ? matches.length : 0;
        });
        $("#results").text(results+ " matches").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#results").hide();
    }
});​
```

This is just a basic implementation to start with. Let me know if it works for you.